# Sum if condition is true and background color is not - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a function with two conditions - Sum if condition is true and sum if background color is not.

Normally I'll use function SUMIFS but here I have one built-in function and one custom function. Both of this functions work fine separately but I cannot combine them together as one.

[image]

To "Sum if condition is true" I've used built-in function SUMIF and for "Sum if background color is not" I've used a function from Script Library.

Here is a link to my spreadsheet [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ug2BsJ18cRrMg_xQ6NKatHFEfyJnpu2kqOmR3l5FGio/edit?usp=sharing)

Additional thing is that I need to sum different columns ex. Values2 with same conditions.

Using @Ritz code I'm trying to modify his code and I have this script:

```
  /**
     * @return The sum of range B where the corresponding value in Column A matches the color
     * @customfunction
     */

function conditionalCheck(color,rangeCondition, rangeSum, criteria){
  var condition = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,rangeCondition,11).getValues();
  var val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,rangeSum,11).getValues();
  var bg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(2,rangeSum,11).getBackgrounds();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
     if(condition[i] == criteria && bg[i] != color){
       sum += val[i];
     }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

But result is that variable "sum" doing concatenation of the values but doesn't sum it. (The result is shown on print screen on cell H10).

I'll be grateful for any clues.

Comment: .getValues() returns e.g `[[1,2],[3,4]]` so inside for loop you need mention the second index

Comment: Thank you @Ritz again. Everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below script. You need to pass the color and range of both the columns as parameters. `=conditionalCheck("#ffff00","A2:B12")`

```
/**
 * @return The sum of range B where the corresponding value in Column A matches the color
 * @customfunction
 */
function conditionalCheck(color,range){
  var val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getValues();
  var bg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getBackgrounds();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
     if(val[i][0] == "A" && bg[i][1] == color){
       sum = sum + val[i][1]
     }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works but sum cells with specific color, and should sum rest of cell. So I've changed only for loop == color to != color.

Comment: I've changed a bit of my question because I need to use this script on different columns, so I cannot use getRange with a1Notation. Can you look at my question again? Thank you.